# Cannot find the package to unsinstall it

Tags: lubuntu

In a Lubuntu OS someone installed the [geosuite](http://boundlessgeo.com/) now i need to uninstall it becuase when i try to update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

i get this error:

```
W: GPG error: http://apt.boundlessgeo.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1DB67044832A0D1F
```

i don't want to fix it, i want to completely remove **everything** even slightly related to it. I do not know if the package is removed or not, and i do not know its name either... Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 0):

You get this error, because someone added this repository to your sources.list

If you want to get rid of the error there are two ways to solve:

First one is to remove this repository if you do not plan to use it. It is not a default repo lubuntu comes with.

You can carefully edit the file

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

And remove the corresponding line.

The second approach is to add the public key for this repoitory if you plan to use it in future.

About the uninstallation of the geosuite package - first you need to know it's name. You can try:

```
apt-cache search geosuite
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get purge <package-name>
```